# Let P(x) be a polynomial of degree 4 , having extremum at $x=1,x=2$ and $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^2+P(x)}{x^2}=2$ Then the value of P(2)

Tags: calculus, derivatives, polynomials

> Let $P(x)$ be a polynomial of degree 4 , having extremum at $x=1,x=2$ and $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^2+P(x)}{x^2}=2.$$ Then what is the value of $P(2)$?

I worked out the limit using L'Hospital got a relation in terms of second derivative of $P$; the other derivative relations are that first derivatives are zero at 1,2.

How can we interpretate these derivative equations to find the function?

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write $P(x) = a + bx + cx^2 + dx^3 + ex^4$. Given the limit statement, we have

$$\lim_{x \to 0} ex^2 + dx + (c + 1) + \frac{b}{x} + \frac{a}{x^2} = 2$$

The only way that this is possible is to have $a = b = 0$ and $c + 1 = 2$; hence $c = 1$.

Furthermore, we have $P'(1) = 0 = P'(2)$, which will give you two more equations in the unknowns $d$ and $e$.

---

Since $P'(x) = 2 x + 3dx^2 + 4ex^3$, we can evaluate at $1$ and $2$ to find

$$2 + 3d + 4e = 0$$

and

$$4(2 + 12d + 64 e) = 0$$

Comment: There is a problem in finding d and e .
the two equations I get are :
$4e+3d+2=0$ AND $4e+3d+1=0$ . Which gives no solution.

Comment: @Simar I've expanded my solution. The equations do have a solution.

Comment: I don't know what i was doing. Thanks though :)

Comment: @Simar You're very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a little late, but instead of formulating the equations, one may also write the function $f'(x)$ first, and then integrate it.
Assuming $f'(x) = (x-2)(x-1)(x-k)$ and evaluating the limit through L'Hospital's rule, we have $k=0$.
On integrating this we have some $g(x) + c = f(x)$, where $c=0$ because of the limit condition.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{p(x)}{x^2}=1$$

So for the existance of limit $p(0)=0$ and using D L hopital rule

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{p'(x)}{2x}=1$$

Again for existance of limit $p'(0)=0$

Given  $p(x)$ be a polynomial of degree $4$ , having extremum at  $x=1,x=2$

So $$p'(x)=A x(x-1)(x-2)=A(x^3-3x^2+2x)$$

$$\int p'(x)dx = p(x)=A\int (x^3-3x^2+2x)dx=A\bigg[\frac{x^4}{4}-x^3+x^2\bigg]+\mathcal{C}$$

Put $x=0$ we have $\mathcal{C}=0$

And put $p'(x)$ into  $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{p'(x)}{2x}=1$$

We have $\displaystyle A=0.5$

So $$p(x)=\frac{1}{2}\bigg(\frac{x^4}{4}-x^3+x^2\bigg)$$

So $$p(2)=0$$